# Hibernate does not create table - some converters

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I read some similar queries on SO, but my problem is a "little different".

I've entity like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "commission_template")
public class CommmissionTemplate {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private Double min;

    private Double max;

    private Double value;

    private boolean active;

    @Convert(converter = LocalDateToSqlConverter.class)
    private LocalDate start;

    @Convert(converter = LocalDateToSqlConverter.class)
    private LocalDate end;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "commission_template_commission_type",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "commission_template_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "type_id", referencedColumnName = "name")}
    )
    private CommissionType type;

// getters/setters etc.
}
```

And configuration in `persistence.xml` like

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="${db.dialect}"/>
```

then when I start y application in log I've:

```
Hibernate: create table commission_template (id int8 not null, active boolean not null, end timestamp, max float8, min float8, start timestamp, value float8, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table commission_template_commission_type (type_id varchar(255), commission_template_id int8 not null, primary key (commission_template_id))
```

and here we have magic because Hibernate does not create table `commission_template`. pgAdmin tell me "no such table". The best thing is that when I turn off application and Hibernate call drops they log that they drop `commission_template` table.

I tried to change name of table and I set it to `prowizje_szablony`...

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "prowizje_szablony" does not exist
  Pozycja: 273
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2077)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1810)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:498)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:386)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:271)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
    ... 77 more
```

any ideas, suggestions or hints?

// edit: IMO, problem is somewhere in converters and Hibernate can't handle table with them.

// workaround: create that table manually via:

```
CREATE TABLE commissiontemplate
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  active boolean,
  start timestamp without time zone,
  "end" timestamp without time zone,
  min double precision,
  max double precision,
  value double precision,
  CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE commissiontemplate
  OWNER TO koziolek;
```

with default name (I know polish is quite nice language where you could call table `chrząszcz`, but please... not in IT) and change DDL to `validate` not nice because we need additional tools to cover schema updates but works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

Hibernate can't create table with column named **`end`** because it is key word, but never ever tell you that. Just log event "create table".

When I create table manually then pgAdmin add `"` to DDL and it works fine. Because I've some habits and always use `"` in queries so manual check of query works ok.

When hibernate perform sql query to this table then I get `SQLGrammarException`... and that was a hint what was wrong. I change column name and now works ok.

Answer (score 0):

According to logs Hibernate is actually creating those tables for you. make sure you are connecting to the same database instance and you are using the same schema as the one Hibernate uses.

You can also try switching to:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

Because create-drop will drop the schema once the SessionFactory gets closed.